# AutoCad 2017 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, autocad

We are running with Autocad 2016 on Windows 8.1 and planning to migrate both Autocad and Windows OS.

Is Autocad 2017 compatible with Windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Autocad's System Requirements](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/System-requirements-for-AutoCAD-2017.html), yes, it's compatible with Windows 10.

Comment: i see some blogs where they say its not working on windows 10, im confused with these blogs.. :/

Comment: I see some blogs that claim that elvis still lives and that the moon landings never happened. This is why its wise to use blogs cautiously as a source of information and test for yourself.

Comment: :P ill  test on my machine hope it works.